# Parse SQL query before it goes to MySQL

Tags: mysql, go

In my Go app I want to be able to analyze a SQL query before to execute it.
I want to get: 
type (update, insert, delete etc). This is easy, but next steps not.
table to be affected,
columns to be updated (on insert/update)
most important - condition, list of columns and values.

**Is there any go library for this?**

Something to pass a sql query and get back some structure with info about this query

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have [`sqlparser`](https://github.com/xwb1989/sqlparser) for golang.

Note that the sqlparser is been pulled out from the database clustering system [`vitess`](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess)

You can use the sql parser like,

```
reader := strings.NewReader("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'a');")

tokens := sqlparser.NewTokenizer(reader)
for {
    stmt, err := sqlparser.ParseNext(tokens)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    // Do your logics with the statements.
}
```

Comment: I would suggest importing the parser from `vitess.io/vitess/go/vt/sqlparser` directly as the above mentioned one has not been maintained for over 4 years now.